# Using regex capture groups in a Cypher query

Tags: regex, neo4j, cypher

In the cypher [documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-where.html#_regular_expressions) it says you can use regexes to match particular -previously known- patterns in a string attribute.

Is it possible to use capture groups as well?

Take an example:

My node attributes are serialised JSON that look like:

```
n.json = '{"name": "John", "gender": "m"}'
n.json = '{"name": "Jane", "gender": "f"}'
```

I want to know relationships between people of different gender:

```
MATCH r=(n)--(m)
WHERE NOT (n.json =~ '.*gender": "(\c)".*')[1] = (m.json =~ '.*gender": "(\c)".*')[1]
RETURN r
```

or something like that.

Comment: You can't do that in Cypher (as far as I know). regex is only for matching.

Comment: I'd be also interested why you didn't store the name and gender as properties on the nodes? This approach is certainly not scaling in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351069/using-regular-expressions-beyond-matching-in-cypher).   The short answer is that backreferences aren't supported in cypher; regular expressions are just for matching.

In general, when I run into problems like what you're facing, I try to deal with them prior to the import step.   I.e. you might start with data, massage it into CSV, and then load the CSV into a graph.   During the manipulation of the CSV, I'd do the pattern matching with some other tool (sed/awk/perl/python/whatever) and then modify the data before it gets loaded into the graph to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use matched groups with an APOC `apoc.text.regexGroups` function:

```
MATCH (a:AppJar)-[:CONTAINS]->(b)
WHERE b.fileName STARTS WITH "/BOOT-INF/lib/event-"
WITH a, b, last(last(apoc.text.regexGroups(b.fileName, '/BOOT-INF/lib/event-([\\d\\.]+).jar'))) as version
SET b.version = version
RETURN a.appName, b.fileName, b.version
LIMIT 100
```