# Neo4j Cyper: Get data from RE

Tags: regex, neo4j, cypher

what I want is to get information from a property in my regular expression, and return a name and a count of how many times the name apers - all this in cypher. My guess is something like this:

```
MATCH (t:Tweet)
WHERE t.body =~ "@(.*?) .*" = k
RETURN k as name, count(k) as number
```

A solution is of course to do:

```
MATCH (t:Tweet)
WHERE t.body =~ "@.*"
RETURN t
```

And the do it in an other language like python - that's not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do what you're trying to do with cypher.  Regular expressions are just for matching.  But for your confirmation, here are two related StackOverflow questions with similar issues, but the same answer as I'm providing here: [Using regex capture groups in cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306243/using-regex-capture-groups-in-a-cypher-query) and [Using regex beyond matching in cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351069/using-regular-expressions-beyond-matching-in-cypher).

On one of those questions, Michael Hunger gave good and appropriate advice about facing these situations:

> In general, when I run into problems like what you're facing, I try to
>   deal with them prior to the import step. I.e. you might start with
>   data, massage it into CSV, and then load the CSV into a graph. During
>   the manipulation of the CSV, I'd do the pattern matching with some
>   other tool (sed/awk/perl/python/whatever) and then modify the data
>   before it gets loaded into the graph to do this sort of thing.

For your problem, you won't be able to avoid doing it in a separate tool.  But of course however you choose to do it, you can always update your nodes with properties that contain the answers, and then query based on that.  It's a work-around, but I think this accurately captures what your options are.